# how to put data in two different table using two different activity

Tags: android, http, android-layout, android-intent, http-headers

Here in my application in the first activity i am using the following code for storing data into mysql.
Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText et;
Button b;
InputStream is;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String name = et.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));


            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert1.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Congrats! ur added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent mainpage = new Intent("com.example.test.PLACE");
                startActivity(mainpage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not connected to DataBase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

For make it simple i have just used only one field here. And now i tried to get another field from the user in other activity and I tried to store that in different table by using the same concept of the above code. But its not getting stored. Can anybody help me out in this issue.. I tried for a long time its not working. Kindly help me.
My other java code used in other is given below.. What i want is i need to get name and place in different activity and i want to store them in different table. Kindly help me..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.place);

    t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    View bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bb.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String place = t.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevalueparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    namevalueparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place", place));


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert11.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevalueparams));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        iss = entity.getContent();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Congrats! ur added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not connected to DataBase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are calling to insert1.php in the upper code and to insert11.php in the code below. If the first works and the second doesn't there has to be a difference from what's inside your two different PHPs.

Expect different results for different code bases :)